# core memory dump when increase number of processors

Tags: c, openmp

I have spent quite some time, trying to figure out the issue but havent been able to trace this thing.

So, the issue is line 203

```
size_t s = getS(n);
```

Basically, if I hardcode s to be (say) 20, things works fine.. but if I determine s based on number of processors (s~600).. things break with coredump error.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./metrics: double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000022eaad0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3768875e66]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x37688789ba]
/usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1[0x326160cdfa]
./metrics[0x401c0b]
./metrics[0x40208d]
./metrics[0x400ff8]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x376881ed5d]
./metrics[0x400bb9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 197296620  
...
```

I am at lost on how to debug this as I am running this code on a cluster and I am noob in C (coming from python world).
Would like to get some help/pointers on how to debug this.

Pasting code here as well.. but I think the paste would be easier.

```
long* generateHeadList(size_t s, long globalhead, size_t n, long TAIL_INDEX, long *new_s){
long *tempheads = (long*) malloc(s * sizeof(long));
tempheads[0] = globalhead;
long k =s;

#pragma omp parallel for

    for (int i=1; i<s; i++)
            tempheads[i] = -2;

#pragma omp parallel for

    for (long i=0; i<s; i++){
        long r = rand() % n;
        if ((r!=globalhead) && (r!=TAIL_INDEX) && !inList(tempheads, r, s)){
            tempheads[i+1] = r;
        }
        else{
            k--;
        }
    }

    *new_s = k;
    long *heads = (long*) malloc(k * sizeof(long));
    long index =0;
    for (long i=0; i<s; i++){
        if (tempheads[i] !=-2){
            heads[index] = tempheads[i];
            index++;
        }
    }

    return heads;
}

void executeParallel( const long* next,long head,  size_t n,long* rank){

long r = 0;
long globHead = head;
long TAIL_INDEX = findTailIndex(next, n);
size_t s = getS(n);

printf("size is %d\n",s);

long new_s;
long *heads;
heads = generateHeadList(s, globHead, n, TAIL_INDEX, &new_s);
}
```

Edit:    executeParallel is the function that is called by name.. Please let me know if that is also desired..(like the how it is called)

Comment: As message says either you `free` a pointer twice or `free` a non allocated pointer .  Seen none `free` statement .

Comment: @ameyCU: but I don't think I am freeing any memory in the code?

Comment: Yeah I was seeing you code. You didn't . But you should for precaution from memory leak.

Comment: Would be good if you provide a `main` function which calls `executeParallel` properly.

Comment: @4566976 Posted the metrics.c code which contains main http://paste.ofcode.org/9B7BQkdZK8NuiigQENENFK

Comment: compile with all warnings & debug info (`-Wall -Wextra -g`) with a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and/or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `generateHeadList` there is a malloc:

```
long *tempheads = (long*) malloc(s * sizeof(long));
```

Then there is a loop:

```
for (long i=0; i<s; i++){
    long r = rand() % n;
    if ((r!=globalhead) && (r!=TAIL_INDEX) && !inList(tempheads, r, s)){
        tempheads[i+1] = r;
    }
    else{
        k--;
    }
}
```

In `tempheads[i+1] = r;` it is written one past the allocated memory. Fix this and try again.

---

I get a segfault because `elements[0].localRanks` is garbage. When I start the loop at index 1 the program terminates normally:

```
 for (long i=1; i<new_s; i++){
      mergeRanks(rank, elements[i].localRanks,n, cumsums[i]);
  }
```

Comment: This fixs the original error but getting a new error..
/tmp/slurmd/job/slurm_script: line 13: 23598 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./metrics
And I am not sure what slurm_script is.. :-/ (there is no such file in path)..
The change i made is for (long i=0; i<s-1; i++) // (s-1) instead of s

Comment: From [http://slurm.schedmd.com/overview.html](http://slurm.schedmd.com/overview.html):
_The Simple Linux Utility for Resource Management (Slurm) is an open source, fault-tolerant, and highly scalable cluster management and job scheduling system for large and small Linux clusters._ Well, I'm sorry I can't help further.

Comment: @Fraz Perhaps the update in my answer helps further.